# How to return an async result from a sync method in vertx?

Tags: java, future, vert.x

I am using executeBlocking from vertx in a for loop to parallelise the processing of a result, and collating the results using a CompositeFuture. Based on all the results, I want to return some value from the method, but lambda function inside CompositeFuture's handler is not letting me do so. How to work with this usecase?

Code for reference:

```
public Response call() throws Exception {
    List<Future> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    //services is a global variable, an arraylist of services
    for(String service: services) {
        Future serviceFuture = Future.future();
        futureList.add(serviceFuture);

        vertx.executeBlocking(implementTask(service, serviceFuture), false, asyncResult -> {
            if (asyncResult.failed()) {
                LOGGER.error("Task FAILED for service {}", service, asyncResult.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    CompositeFuture.all(futureList).setHandler(asyncResult -> {
        if(asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Task completed successfully");
            return new Response(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS);
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Task FAILED", asyncResult.cause());
            return new Response(ResponseStatus.FAILED);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
Your `call()` method should return `Future<Result>` and not the `Result`. Then you would need to attach the callback handler on your original caller. This is the way that async methods propagate the result in Vert.x.

```
public Future<Response> call() throws Exception {
    Promise<Response> promise = Promise.promise();
    List<Future> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    //services is a global variable, an arraylist of services
    for(String service: services) {
        Future serviceFuture = Future.future();
        futureList.add(serviceFuture);

        vertx.executeBlocking(implementTask(service, serviceFuture), false, asyncResult -> {
            if (asyncResult.failed()) {
                LOGGER.error("Task FAILED for service {}", service, asyncResult.cause());
            }
        });
    }

    CompositeFuture.all(futureList).setHandler(asyncResult -> {
        if(asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Task completed successfully");
            promise.complete(new Response(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS));
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Task FAILED", asyncResult.cause());
            promise.fail("Failed");
        }
    });
    return promise.future();
}
```

Then the call would look like this:

```
object.call().onSuccess(resultHandler - > {
    //Code when call succeeded
}).onFailure(failureHandler - > {
    //Code when call failed
});
```

Note: This example is using Vert.x 4. If you are using a version of Vert.x less than 4, then the syntax is a bit different, but the point stays the same.